# Restore default sizing behavior for Grid WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, grid

I have one Grid who's `Height` I bind to another Grid's `ActualHeight` in code. This part is no problem. But after a specific user interaction I want to remove this binding and have the Grid behave as it normally would and size itself to its content.

During this "user interaction", the size of the bound grid's content increases in Height as I add more content to the StackPanel.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <StackPanel>
        ....
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

<Grid x:Name="grid2">
    <StackPanel>
        ....
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
Binding HeightBinding = new Binding("ActualHeight");
HeightBinding.Source = grid2;
grid1.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, HeightBinding);
```

So when I remove the binding I expect the Grid to return to normal and increase in size as well. This is not the case. I have tried the following with no success:

```
1) BindingOperations.ClearBinding(grid1, Grid.HeightProperty);

2) grid1.Height = Double.NaN;
   grid1.InvalidateMeasure();

3) Binding binding = new Binding();
   grid1.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, binding );

4) BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(grid1);
```

Comment: What kind of parent panel is your `Grid` in? It's possible you have it hosted in a panel that automatically stretches it's children to fill all available space.

Comment: The parent is also a grid and the child is a stackpanel